# Putting label in middle third of UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

On my storyboard, I have a UIView box with a label in it and I'd like to put the label in the exact middle third of the view. My current solution is to put a stack in the view and put 3 labels, a blank label, the label I'm using, and another label. I then put constraints on the stack to fill up the view and set the stack to Fill Equally, which makes the label I'm using be exactly the middle third of the view.

The solution works fine and it works on any device using auto layout, but it also means that I have two blank labels in my view controller that clutter things up. I can continue using this method, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the centerX constraint's multiplier to 2/3

```
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: view,
                                         attribute: .centerX,
                                         relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: label,
                                         attribute: .centerX,
                                         multiplier: 2.0 / 3.0,
                                         constant: 0)
```